# How can i remove the file name from a path directory string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the line:

```
string f = Path.GetFullPath("c:\\t.txt").Replace(":", "").Replace("\\", "/");
```

I tried something with:  string t = f.LastIndexOf("/"); but that's not working.
f now is: c/t.txt
I need that f will be only c/
And if the directory with the file name was: c:\subdir\sub\t.txt
So in the end f should be: c/subdir/sub without the t.txt in the end.

I tried this now:

The problem is that when i'm doing:

```
f.TargetFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(txf);
f.TargetFolder = Path.GetFullPath(txf).Replace(":", "").Replace("\\", "/");
```

the second line with the Replace leave me with C/test.txt I tried to make only replace for the string it self without GetFullPath only fro the txf but same result in TargetFolder i have c/test.txt and i need to be with only c/ The line with the Replace is not good it's not giving me the result i need.

Comment: `Path.GetDirectoryName();` then replace as needed

Comment: Why do you want to switch the slashes?

Comment: And why do you want to get rid of the `:` character from the root?

Comment: or something like `f = f.Substring(0, f.Length - 5);` ?

Comment: royap since i'm uploading the file to my ftp server and the format of file path for uploading should be: ftp://ftp.mysite.com/c/test.txt so the file test.txt will be in directory c. I don't want to have C: as diurectory on my ftp server.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the part of a file path that represents the directory that contains the file. For example:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\path\\to\\file.txt"); // returns C:\path\to
```

More examples:

```
INPUT                              OUTPUT
---------------------------------  ------------------------
C:\path\to\file.txt                C:\path\to
C:\path\to\                        C:\path\to
C:\path\to                         C:\path
C:\path\                           C:\path
C:\path                            C:\
C:\                                (null)
C:                                 (null)
\path\to\file.txt                  \path\to
path\to\file.txt                   path\to
\\server\share\path\to\file.txt    \\server\share\path\to
\\server\share                     (null)
\\server                           (null)
```

`(null)` above indicates that the return value is the `null` value, **not a string**.